# Could not find or load main class sun.security.tools.jarsigner.Main

Tags: java, android, powershell, jarsigner

I've got a build script written in PowerShell that needs to sign an Android APK.

```
task PackageForAndroid -Description "Get the Android apk ready for deployment" {
    if (! (Test-Path env:JAVA_HOME)) {
        Write-Host "Please install the Java JDK and set your JAVA_HOME environment variable."
        exit 1        
    }

    $javaHome = (Get-Item env:JAVA_HOME).Value
    Exec { & "$javaHome\bin\jarsigner.exe" -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore $buildDir/certs/cosmicgame.keystore -signedjar $buildOutputDir/$androidApkName-signed.apk $buildOutputDir/$androidApkName.apk cosmicgame } "Signing the Android apk Failed"

    # Now zipalign it.  The -v parameter tells zipalign to verify the APK afterwards.
    Exec { & "$buildDir\modules\zipalign.exe" -f -v 4 $buildOutputDir/$androidApkName-signed.apk $buildArtifactsDir/$androidApkName.$version.$buildNumber.apk } "Zipaligning the Android apk Failed"
}
```

When I check the output of `$javaHome = (Get-Item env:JAVA_HOME).Value` I get the appropriate path (`C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`).

When I navigate into the bin directory, the `jarsigner.exe` is in there.

I've updated both my Android SDK to include the latest stuff, and I've updated JAVA to the latest as well.

What would cause this error?

> Error: Could not find or load main class sun.security.tools.jarsigner.Main

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 the location of Jar Signer main class in tools.jar has changed to sun.security.tools.jarsigner.Main, 
I suspect that you are running jarsigner.exe from a Java 8 distribution while having the Java 7 tools.jar in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after the update of the ***jdk1.8.0_121*** to ***jdk1.8.0_131***. The **tools.jar** is missing in the *lib* folder. Fortunately, version 121 was used during the update and was not erased so I was able to copy the **tools.jar** into the *lib* folder of the new version.

For me, it is just a workaround to unlock my situation.